# how to authenticate in jira with python

Tags: python-3.x, jira

```
from jira.client import JIRA

jira_options={'server': 'https://abcjira.atlassian.net/login?dest-      url=%2Fsecure%2FMyJiraHome.jspa'}

jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('user','password'))
```

I want to do basic authentication in jira with python. Wrote above code but it gives me traceback. Could anyone please tell me what is the problem here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lab.py", line 5, in <module>
    jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('user','password'))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 261, in __init__
    si = self.server_info()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 1619, in     server_info

    return self._get_json('serverInfo')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 2040, in   _get_json
    raise e
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 2037, in _get_json
    r_json = json_loads(r)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\jira\utils.py", line 81, in json_loads
    return json.loads(r.text)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 4 column 1 (char 3)
```

Comment: Those six spaces in `dest-      url` look wrong. Shouldn't that be `dest-url` with no spaces? Try removing those spaces and see if you get the same error, or a different error.

Comment: No, those spaces is not the issue

Comment: It can't parse some JSON object. The question is which one, either the url you're passing in or something returned from JIRA. Try Fiddler to see the communication (if any)

Comment: I've edited your code dump - now go change your login pssword for JIRA (and possibly a number of other sites)

Comment: whats the outcome here?